# How to use index & length in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of element in a div that I'm displaying in a carousel and I would like to add in the content of each element a text showing the position of the div within the carousel : example : 1/4 for the 1st element, 2/4 for the second and so on...

I get that I should use INDEX() and LENGTH() but can't get my head around how to implement it.

The expected result would be

```html
<div class="toolsCarousel">
<div>Content for 1/4</div>
<div>Content for 2/4</div>
<div>Content for 3/4</div>
<div>Content for 4/4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You need a loop (or something similar). You need something to change the text content of the divs. You need a way to determine the number of elements...

Comment: There is neither an `INDEX()` nor a `LENGTH()` method in jQuery. There is an [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method and a [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property. Please show how you've tried to use those.

Comment: There's no `.length()` method. Did you read what `.index()` does, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toolsCarousel > div").each(function(index, element) {
    var c = index + 1;
    var l = $(".toolsCarousel > div").length;
    $(element).append($("<p>").html(c + "/" + l));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolsCarousel">
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

This uses the `.each()` method to iterate over each of the DIV elements. It is passed the `index` and the `element`. The Index is zero based, so to get a proper count, you must increase it by 1.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/length/